# How to call GetCostAndUsage of AWS API In PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, post, aws-api-gateway

GetCostAndUsage Retrieves cost and usage metrics for your account.

More info about the api is given at this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/latest/APIReference/API_GetCostAndUsage.html .

I am not sure how to make this call using PHP.
What to send in authorization and what credentials i need to send.

Please can someone guide me with an example post request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS documentation provides SDK for calling [GetCostAndUsage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-ce-2017-10-25.html#getcostandusage). Also, it [explains](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_index.html) how to setup credentials for AWS SDK for PHP as well as it provides numerous examples ([here](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/php/example_code/sns) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/examples_index.html)) of how to use it with various services.

Comment: How can i get Bill Details By Account. Which api to use for that? 
Can you help me out?

Comment: @mahethekiller Not sure. Probably you could make new question for that.